# C# WinForms Cannot continuously read mouse position with MouseMove and cannot read button press with MouseHover

Tags: c#, winforms

In winForms I want to be able to have an event called continuously while I hold a mouse button down over a user control

If I use `MouseMove` event, I can get `MouseEventArgs` where I can read the mouse button press

If I use `MouseHover`, I can only get `EventArgs` where I cannot read the mouse button press

The code for event is below:

```
    private void Joystick_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            if (MoveorRot == false)
            {
                new_mouseDownLocation_Rot = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
                double angle_old = 57.2957795131 * Math.Atan2(mouseDownLocation_Rot.X - WIDTH, mouseDownLocation_Rot.Y - HEIGHT);
                double angle_new = 57.2957795131 * Math.Atan2(new_mouseDownLocation_Rot.X - WIDTH, new_mouseDownLocation_Rot.Y - HEIGHT);
                double[] move = { 0.0, 0.0, angle_old - angle_new };
                if (stage != null)
                    stage.PointToPoint(move);
            }
            else
            {
                Point new_mouseDownLocation_Move = new Point(e.X, e.Y);

                int move_x = mouseDownLocation_Move.X - new_mouseDownLocation_Move.X;
                int move_y = mouseDownLocation_Move.Y - new_mouseDownLocation_Move.Y;
                joy.X = WIDTH - move_x;
                joy.Y = HEIGHT - move_y;

                double[] move = { (double)move_x, (double)move_y, 0.0 };
                if (stage != null)
                    stage.PointToPoint(move);
            }
            this.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

The problem is that it stops moving when the mouse stops moving, because the event is not getting called

I want the event to get called at any time whenever the mouse is over the control, but the code to be only executed when the mouse button is pressed

When I use the MouseHover event,

```
   private void Joystick_MouseMove(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)  
        {
        ....
```

'e.Button'  is not available in `EventArgs`, I cannot convert `EventArgs` to `MouseEventArgs`

I tried setting a boolean on `MouseUp` and `MouseDow`n but It sometimes glitching out and `MouseUp` doesn't always get called.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You can try this property (and use MouseHover): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.cursor.position?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

Comment: `Joystick.PointToClient(MousePosition)`

Comment: But how would I capture whether the mosue button is clicked?

Comment: `if (Control.MouseButtons == MouseButtons.Left) { ... }`.

Comment: When the Mouse is clicked, of course you get a `MouseDown` event -- BTW, in the OP you're showing the `MouseMove` event handler twice -- You can always use a Timer to check the position of the Mouse Pointer

Answer (score 1):

Try use `MousePosition` in MouseHover event

Comment: how do I get MousePosition and out of what? How would I get button click from this? Can you please provide some code in the answer?